# Open a calendar that appears only on clicking the right side of an input box

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a calendar that opens up on clicking on the black arrow(marked in the image). This black arrow would appear only on hovering to the right extreme of this input box.
I tried to click on the input tag, but it does not show the calendar as the back arrow doesn't appear. How can I make the calendar appear?

This is how the element looks in inspecting it.

`<input type="week" name="startWeek">`

Im using Selenium  web-driver with Java.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use `mousehover` commands provided by `selenium`

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? If you have to hover, have you tried hovering and then clicking? There are plenty of questions on SO and elsewhere dealing with how to hover, etc. Read those and try some code then come back and update your question with your code and the issue if you can't get it solved yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for this. The workaround is to pass the date directly to the calendar element using sendkeys method.

`getElement(calendar).sendKeys( "03012016")`;

This will enter the date directly onto the calendar field.